# Python/Requests returns 401 but same url in browser works as expected

Tags: python, rest, python-requests, python-3.6

Doing a requests.post with params returns 401

If I print request.url and follow it in a browser it works just fine.

The authorization is provided as an api key in an url parameter.

I can't figure out why the url would work just fine in the browser but not via requests. To clarify the url i'm following is the one that requests has built.

Comment: In a browser or in the browser? I guess your browser has some cookies set. Trace the requests in the dev console and replicate the request with all the headers in Python.

Comment: Try a private/incognito session on the browser to rule out cookies, if it still works try changing the user agent in requests

Comment: Tried incognito; still works. Using chrome.

Comment: Figured it out; apparently despite the documentation that states, requests can be made either post/get only get works, had trouble noticing this before as they return invalid json. Thanks for the suggestions.